# Are databases created in Android Studio secured?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, security

I've developed an app using an SQLite database that's stored locally on a device. Are other apps able to access this database and read it and if so, how can I stop that? I haven't implemented any kind of contact manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether other apps can access the database depends on how you've created the database.

Android apps have access to app-specific storage, and to shared storage. If you've placed the database in app specific storage, it's private to your app.

The `getFilesDir()` method returns the file system path for the root of app specific storage.

For more information: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

If you've used "sqlite helper", it places the database file in app specific storage by default, so you're safe:

> Just like files that you save on the device's internal storage, Android stores your database in your app's private folder. Your data is secure, because by default this area is not accessible to other apps or the user.

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite